# How to Setup Local Store with Static Data in Relay Modern

Tags: javascript, reactjs, relayjs, relaymodern

I'm building a React app that fetches data from a server and also passes static data to various components based on a user's selection from a dropdown menu. I'd like to use Relay Modern, but I've been unable to find anything in the docs about whether it supports manually loading static data to the store. Anyone know if this is possible/how to implement?

btw, I've seen a few similar questions about this here and elsewhere. But, it appeared that those pertained to Relay Classic rather than Relay Modern, which implemented massive changes.

Answer (score 1):

I have have asked myself the same question. There must be  a way to hydrate the `Store`/`RecordSource`. As a workaround I have been doing something like this. I create a query for the data that I want to add to the store and call `commitPayload`.

```js
import {
  createOperationSelector,
  getOperation
} from 'relay-runtime';

const query = graphql `{ viewer { name } }`;

const environment = new Environment(...);

environment.commitPayload(createOperationSelector(getOperation(query)), {
  viewer: {
    name: 'Me'
  }
});
```

Wondering if anyone from the relay team has some insight?

Comment: This is also helpful when you want to bypass or replace the network layer in the case of subscriptions (my use case). Specifically, I use this to build functionality similar to the [updateQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/subscriptions) in Apollo, where custom client-side logic can be used to add a single new comment to an existing entry without reloading all existing comments for that entry from the server.